# Error in discord.py rewrite: discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: question is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I keep having this error: discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: question is a required argument that is missing.
I dont see anything wrong with my code at all and im using rewrite, please have a look:

```
@client.command(aliases =['insultme', 'plzinsult'])
async def _insultme(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['You make it impossible to underestimate you',
                 'I may love to shop but i, myself, will never buy your bullshit.',]
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Question:', description=question, color=0x2332e4, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Answer:', value=random.choice(responses), inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I have done this exact same code just different responses, aliases and async def's and its worked just fine please help i dont know whats wrong.

picture of the code [here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADPOc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same error so I know how to fix it!

This is what your code *should* be.

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['insultme', 'plzinsult'])
async def insultme(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['You make it impossible to underestimate you', 'I may love to shop but i,myself, will never buy your bullshit.',]
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Question:', description=question, color=0x2332e4, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Answer:', value=random.choice(responses), inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

If there are any more errors contact me via discord! `DrNano#9195`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this!

```py
@client.command(aliases=['insult me', 'plzinsult'])
async def insultme(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['You make it impossible to underestimate you', 'I may love to shop but i,myself, will never buy your bullshit.',]
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Question:', description=random.choice(responses), color=0x2332e4, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```